# python socket.gethostbyaddr sometimes skips hostname

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to print name of machine which is **host10** with **socket.gethostbyaddr('10.10.10.1')** an most of the time it is successful

```
('host10.example.com', [], ['10.10.10.1'])
```

but sometimes I am getting only domain name without host10 portion

```
('example.com', [], ['10.10.10.1'])
```

Is there a way to make it more reliable, repeatable ?

Comment: IMO real culprit is your dns.

Comment: Try [`socket.getfqdn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getfqdn)?